# MSMQ Post Message

Tags: powershell, msmq

I am a complete novice when it comes to PowerShell, but have been investigating the best way to test a message queue I have set up (MSMQ). 
So far I have been able to run the following in Powershell to obtain all of my queues to see what is present:

```
gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue -computerName . |
ft -prop Name, MessagesInQueue
```

This returns a list of MSMQ queues I have available.
I now want to post a message to only one of the returned queues named to test the connection. My queue is named:

```
<server>\private$\<queuename>
```

I have attempted using the following but have had no luck:

```
$myqueue = '.\Private$\portalemailqueue'
$MyQueue.Send("<<Message>>", "test1")

Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Send'.
At line:3 char:1
+ $MyQueue.Send("<<Message>>", "test1")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this. Does anyone have any good resources or code to do this?

Answer (score 6):

As the error says, your `$MyQueue` object is just a string, nothing special about it.

You can use the .NET `System.Messaging` namespace to work with message queue instances:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Messaging
$MyQueuePath = '.\Private$\portalemailqueue'
$MyQueue = if([System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Exists($MyQueuePath)) {
    # Open existing queue
    New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $MyQueuePath
} else {
    # Or create it 
    [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Create($MyQueuePath)
}
# Now you can call $MyQueue.Send()
```